# How to merge two tables with possible NULL values in the UNIQUE index?

Tags: postgresql, null, upsert, postgresql-10, unique-index

How to merge (upsert & delete orphan rows) to `tableA`?

`tableA`:

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| company | option | category | rates |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | d        | 2     | *
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 3     | **
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| d       | f      | d        | 1     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

`*` denotes orphan row*.
`**` denotes value to change (*3* -> *4*).

Only touch companies existing in `tableB` (`a` & `c` in the example, leave `d` alone).

`tableB`:

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| company | option | category | rates |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

There is a unique index on `(company, option, category)` in both tables.

Desired resulting `tableA`:

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| company | option | category | rates |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 4     | <-
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| d       | f      | d        | 1     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Only the second row `(a,f,d,2)` was deleted and `rates` was changed from *3* to  *4* for `(a,g,e)`.

Here is a fiddle: https://rextester.com/QUVC30763

I'm thinking to first delete the orphan row with this:

```
DELETE from tableA
 USING tableB
 WHERE 
   -- ignore rows with IDs that don't exist in tableB
   tableA.company = tableB.company
   -- ignore rows that have an exact all-column match in tableB
   AND NOT EXISTS 
      (select * from tableB 
      where tableB.company is not distinct from tableA.company 
      AND tableB.option is not distinct from tableA.option 
      AND tableB.category is not distinct from tableA.category );
```

Then upsert with this:

```
 INSERT INTO tableA (company, option, category, rates) 
   SELECT company, option, category, rates
   FROM   tableB
 ON CONFLICT (company, option, category) 
 DO update
   set rates= EXCLUDED.rates
 WHERE 
      tableA.rates IS DISTINCT FROM 
      EXCLUDED.rates;
```

But the problem with the upsert function is that it can't handle nullable fields. I have to set `-1` in place of `null` or else the function won't be able to know if there are duplicates or not. I feel like setting `-1` in place of `null` will create many workarounds in the future, so I'd like to avoid that if I can.

**Note:** I found that `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` is probably the way to go:

- [Make MERGE on PostgreSQL 9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368083/make-merge-on-postgresql-9-5)

But I haven't seen a query suitable for my case. And I'm not sure if it's possible with nullable fields. Hence **the question:**
Is there a clean way to merge with nullable fields?

Comment: IIUC, your objective is to update *sets* of rows in `tableA` to the new state found in `tableB`, not touching rows where the `company` is not found in `tableB` at all. Sets are defined by their shared `company` value.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Are you aware that multiple entries of `(a, f, null)` for `(company, option, category)` are *allowed* in a `UNIQUE` index? Since `null` values are not considered equal. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/939860. So no conflict for those in `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`

Comment: Yes, but the upsert function won't be able to distinguish if it's unique if there are `null` values and the `unique` index won't be able to know. Here's the schema: https://rextester.com/FQA74908

Comment: I don't see constraints or indexes other than `NOT NULL` in the schema. What about the essential (conflicted) unique index? PK? `option` & `category` can both be `NULL`? Even at the same time? And `NULL` values are to be considered equal for your purpose?

Comment: I've added fork with unique index: https://rextester.com/QUVC30763. Yes `option` and `category` can be `null` at the same time, and yes they are considered as equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right path. But there is a design problem with `NULL` vs. `UNIQUE`:

The columns `option` and `category` can be `NULL`. And `NULL` is to be considered equal in those cases. Your current unique indexes do ***not*** consider `NULL` values to be equal, hence do not enforce your requirements. This creates ambiguities even before you start to merge. The `NULL` value is no good for what you are trying to implement. Working around this will create a lot more work and additional points of failure. Consider using a special value instead of `NULL` and everything falls into place. You were considering `-1`. Anything that naturally makes sense for your actual data type and the nature of the attribute.

That said, the **`DELETE`** has an additional, subtly hidden problem: it would try to delete orphan rows as many times as there are matches on `company` in `tableB`. Nothing breaks since excess attempts do nothing, but it's **needlessly expensive**. Use `EXISTS` twice instead:

```
DELETE FROM tableA a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tableB b
   WHERE a.company = b.company
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tableB b
   WHERE (a.company, a.option, a.category) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM
         (b.company, b.option, b.category)
   );
```

If you insist on working with `NULL` values, splitting the UPSERT into `UPDATE`, followed by `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` would be the workaround. Simpler and cheaper if you don't have concurrent writes to the table. `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` works without specifying a conflict target, so you could implement your requirements with several partial indexes and get this to work. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> For `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, it is optional to specify a
>   *`conflict_target`*; when omitted, conflicts with all usable constraints
>   (and unique indexes) are handled. For `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, a
>   *`conflict_target`* must be provided.

But if you fix your schema with a *working* `UNIQUE` index or constraint, the UPSERT you already have serves nicely.

And make sure there are no concurrent writes to the table or you may face race conditions and / or deadlocks unless you do more ...

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer. I will use `-1` or something that makes sense for the field. I've learned so much with this interaction, very grateful for your time.

Comment: Would this a working unique index? `ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT tableA_uq UNIQUE (company, option, category);`

Comment: Only if you define all three columns `NOT NULL` additionally. `UNIQUE` constraint and index behave the same in this respect, so switching the index for a constraint does not solve the problem.